# How to make a photo grid?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android development and I'm trying to make a photo grid of even squares – three in a row, N number of rows. I have some idea, but it doesn't work correctly. It turns out a white screen. Only if you don't set the size for ConstraintLayout in photo.xml. And I need a row of exactly three squares stretched across the width of the screen. Here are the layouts and activity. How do you see the solution? Thank you so much!

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@color/accent1_300"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

photo.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@color/accent1_300"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.kennyromanov.home_gallery;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridLayout Content = findViewById(R.id.Content);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            View photo = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.photo, null);
            Content.addView(photo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WHy do both layout files have a grid layout?  It makes sense to have 2 layouts, one for the photo and one for the activity.  But there should only be a grid in one.  Your code here would make each element be its own grid, which isn't correct.

Also, I'd consider ditching GridLayout entirely for a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager.  It isn't necessary for this simple of an example, but it would greatly help if N rows becomes large enough to require scrolling.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks for your advices! But isn't the layout inflates, starting from the second level of nesting?

Comment: There's no nesting needed here-  you use gridlayout once and it does a grid.  You don't need one grid for the rows and one for the columns